# plot pandas DataFrame with condition columns

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have this kind of pandas.DataFrame. "a","b" are conditions when getting "x" and "y".

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,0,.1], [10,20,1,.5], [100,200,0,.33], [100,200,1,.11]], columns=["a", "b", "x", "y"])
df
```

[image]

I need to plot line charts of (x,y) colums with respect to the same condition. The expected result plot is:

[image]
[image]

Of course, this image is manually given by the following code:

```
pd.DataFrame([[0,.1],[1,.5]]).plot(kind="line", x=0, y=1, style="-", legend=None, title="a: 10, b: 20")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.figure()
pd.DataFrame([[0,.33],[1,.11]]).plot(kind="line", x=0, y=1, style="-", legend=None, title="a: 100, b: 200")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

My question is how to dynamically make plots like above when getting a dataframe including condition columns, x and y.

#### Update

Column names are fixed. However, values of condition columns is dynamically changed. So, I can not use the values 10, 20, 100, 200.

#### Update2

If I have the below "filter_with_a_and_b" method, I think the problem solved:

```
def filter_with_a_and_b(df, a_b):
    # how to implement?

a_b_list = df.drop_duplicates(["a","b"])
new_df_list = filter_with_a_and_b(df, a_b)
for idx, df in enumerate(new_df_list):
    df.plot(title=a_b_list[idx])
```

Comment: what is the source for your conditions and on which columns do you want to apply those conditions?

Comment: @MaxU Please, see update2.

Comment: so you want to filter columns `a` and `b` with values of columns `a` and `b`, which would produce the same data frame - is that what you want? ;)

Comment: do you just want to plot (x, y) for all unique combinations of (a, b)? I.e. if you have three different combinations of (a,b) - that would produce three plots with corresponding (x,y) - do i understand it correctly?

Comment: @MaxU yes! Absolutely

Comment: i've updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 16, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
df.loc[(df.a == 10) & (df.b == 20), ['x','y']].plot(title='a: 10, b: 20')
```

and now let's do it bit smarter:

```
cond = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
df.loc[(df.a == cond['a']) & (df.b == cond['b']), ['x','y']].plot(title='a: {a}, b: {b}'.format(**cond))
```

or using `query()`:

```
q = 'a == 100 and b == 200'
df.query(q)[['x','y']].plot(title=q)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
a_b_list = df[['a','b']].drop_duplicates()

[df.loc[(df.a == tup[0]) & (df.b == tup[1]), ['x','y']] \
   .plot(x='x', y='y', kind='line', style='-',title='a: {0[0]}, b: {0[1]}'.format(tup)) \
   .set_ylabel('y')
 for tup in a_b_list.itertuples(index=False)]
```

Comment: @MaxU Sorry, I mean condition values should be dynamically changed.

Comment: @rkjt50r983, how do you want to change them dynamically? Could you make an example?